# How to properly navigate to previous page with getx?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-getx

I have a pages
A>B>C>D>E
I want to navigate back from page E>B>A

I tried with

```
 Get.offNamedUntil('B', (route) => false);
```

But it worked like E>B and then doesn't redirect back to A. Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you forget a `/` in the named route, and as a recommendation, don't return `false` in the callback, set a condition to stop if the named route was not found in the routes stack, as example use `route.isFirst` :

```
Get.offNamedUntil('/B', (Route<dynamic> route) => route.isFirst);
```